# Deployed Gatsby + Netlify site triggers a blank page when refreshing any page except home page. Doesn’t happen locally

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, gatsby, netlify, react-dom

This is my first Gatsby site so the solution may be very simple, the site is: universityfc.org

Whenever I refresh a page that is not the homepage (or directly navigate to the URL of ones of those pages) I get a completely blank  page. This does not happen when I host the page locally using npm start, however locally upon refresh a blank page appears for about a second and then is replaced with the correct content.

Inspecting the blank page points to an error with react-mdl and react-dom but if this is the case I'm not sure why everything works until refreshed and why it works locally.

```
uni_soccer_logo.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social1.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social2.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social3.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social4.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social5.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social6.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social7.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social8.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social9.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
social10.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
react-dom.production.min.js:209 TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined
    at t.value (MDLComponent.js:82)
    at lo (react-dom.production.min.js:212)
    at pu (react-dom.production.min.js:255)
    at KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at jl (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at du (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Zo (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at qo (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at Du (react-dom.production.min.js:281)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:284
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:209
i.componentDidCatch.n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:227
fi @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
lo @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
pu @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
jl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
du @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
Zo @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
jl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Hl @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Bl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
tu @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
ju @ react-dom.production.min.js:284
t.hydrate @ react-dom.production.min.js:290
(anonymous) @ production-app.js:180
react-dom.production.min.js:209 TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined
    at t.value (MDLComponent.js:82)
    at lo (react-dom.production.min.js:212)
    at pu (react-dom.production.min.js:255)
    at KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at jl (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at du (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Zo (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at qo (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at Du (react-dom.production.min.js:281)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:284
Za @ react-dom.production.min.js:209
n.callback @ react-dom.production.min.js:226
fi @ react-dom.production.min.js:131
lo @ react-dom.production.min.js:212
pu @ react-dom.production.min.js:255
KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
jl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
du @ react-dom.production.min.js:248
Zo @ react-dom.production.min.js:239
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
jl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
Hl @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Bl @ react-dom.production.min.js:122
tu @ react-dom.production.min.js:240
ju @ react-dom.production.min.js:284
t.hydrate @ react-dom.production.min.js:290
(anonymous) @ production-app.js:180
react-dom.production.min.js:123 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined
    at t.value (MDLComponent.js:82)
    at lo (react-dom.production.min.js:212)
    at pu (react-dom.production.min.js:255)
    at KqkS.t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
    at jl (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
    at du (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
    at Zo (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
    at qo (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at Du (react-dom.production.min.js:281)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:284
```

The page components are all located in src/pages and I navigate to these pages using Gatsby Link as below. I've tried "/page" and "/page/" paths with both giving the same blank page on refresh.

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

<Link to="/history">Club History</Link>
<Link to="/teams/">Teams</Link>
```

Previously I have used create-react-app and set up routing with Switch and Route from react-router-dom in a separate view component that I’ve included in the App component. I thought this was unnecessary in Gatsby as it was all handled automatically, but perhaps I am missing something basic.

I have searched through all similar questions and read over the Gatsby docs many times but can’t seem to find what I’m doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen in a `build` mode locally? It should, it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeElements' of undefined` when accessing to `/teams`. Can you provide more information about what's `upgradeElements`?

Comment: You should fix the `build` locally before pushing the project to Netlify first then. Try updating your answer with your "lots of errors". Keep in mind that `warnings` are not `errors`. Both should be fixed but `warnings` won't break your code. Maybe it helps you to debug and to find the initial error.

Comment: Thanks. I tried building locally and the links to the pages immediately triggered a blank page on click (instead of just not working on refresh). After trying a few things I changed all the gatsby `Link` to traditional `<a>` tag and this fixed the problem locally and on Netlify.

Comment: I also added ```import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js'; ``` to the navbar file which may also have fixed the mdl related error